# How to load records dynamically in listview with help of Bottom progressbar

Tags: android, listview

Hi i am very new for android and in my case i have 200 above records i have to show in my list-view that's why i request to server offset value

so that based on offset value server sending records for this i wrote below code but duplicate records also adding in my ArrayList  how can we resolve please help

my code is below very clearly and i am sending server link also please help me

### code:-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView lv;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListViewAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    private int scrollState;
    private int offset = 0;
    private boolean flag = false;
    private boolean loadingMore = false;
    ProgressBar pb;
    private int scrollpos;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        } else {
            arrayList = (ArrayList<String>)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("list");
        }

        //Adding footer for ListView:-
        pb = new ProgressBar(this);
        lv.addFooterView(pb);

        //Setting Adapter:-
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, arrayList);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        if (!flag) {
            new loadMoreListView().execute();
            flag = true;
        }

        lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                MainActivity.this.scrollState = scrollState;
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
                                 int totalItemCount) {

                scrollpos = totalItemCount;
                int lastPos = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;

                if (lastPos == totalItemCount && !loadingMore) {

                    if (totalItemCount < 250) {
                        new loadMoreListView().execute();
                    } else {
                        lv.removeFooterView(pb);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putSerializable("list", arrayList);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        arrayList = (ArrayList<String>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("list");
    }

    private class loadMoreListView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        protected String doInBackground(Void... unused) {
            loadingMore = true;
            String result = null;
            String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/imdb_top_250.php?offset=" + offset;
            try {
                URL mUrl = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) mUrl.openConnection();
                urlConnection.connect();
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String str = "";
                while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(str);
                }
                result = buffer.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            System.out.println("Result is"+result);

            if (result != null) {
                try {

                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(result);
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        arrayList.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"));
                    }

                    System.out.println("arry list count is====>"+arrayList.size());
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    offset++;
                   // offset = offset + 10;
                    loadingMore = false;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                lv.removeFooterView(pb);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how many items you are in getting initially, by code I guess it is 250, than your offset should be your listsize + 1

```
//after retrieving data offset should be
offset = arraylist.size() + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

move offset++; inside loop so it will increase to current record number and you will get next records

currently you only increasing it to once that's why it will giving records from next to one i.e. duplicate record except first.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    arrayList.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"));
    offset++;
}
```